# How to view Azure storage account queue

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a queue in my Azure storage account queue. I want a tool to see what is inside that queue.

I have tried 'CloudBerry Explorer for Azure Blob Storage', but that does not let me see the content of the queue.

And I tried 'Azure Storage Explorer', I can only see top 32 messages of the queue.
Can I see all the message in the queue?

And is there a tool allow me to change the order of message in the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Queue storage does not guarantee message ordering and therefore does not also provide a way to reorder messages.

There are two ways to see the contents of existing messages: [Get Messages API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179474.aspx) and [Peek Messages API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179472.aspx). Both allow retrieving up to 32 messages at a time, so there is no way to view more than 32 messages without making the first 32 invisible (dequeue) first with [Get Messages API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179474.aspx).